# How to handle returning a promise when one is already running?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, queue

I have a javascript class which currently makes a few asynchronous calls, adds elements to the DOM then calls a user callback. Something like this:

```
api.load = function() {
    if (api.loading || api.loaded)
        return;

    api.loading = true;
    makeAsyncCalls(); // will set api.loaded = true and run all pendingReady
}

api.ready = function(callback) {
    if (!api.loaded) {
        pendingReady.push(callback);
    }
    callback(someValue);
}
```

This allows me to handle multiple calls to `load` and `ready`.

I'm now trying to update this to make use of javascripts `Promise`. The above code would become something like:

```
api.load = function() {
    if (api.loaded) {
        // callers attached .then() will still fire
        return Promise.resolve(someValue);
    }

    if (api.loading) {
        // Not sure how to handle this
    }

    api.loading = true;
    return makeAsyncCalls(); // Which returns a Promise
}
```

I don't know how to handle the case where the first Promise has started but not yet completely loaded (resolved in promise speech). The only method I can think of is to return a Promise which wraps a call to `setInterval` checking the status. Surely there is a better approach. Any suggestions?

To make this clearer. Every call to `api.load` must return a `Promise` or `thenable`. The first call will initiate the async methods. Further calls need to return a `Promise` which can only resolve or reject AFTER the initial `Promise` has completed.

Chaining the promises will only work if no values are passed to the success handler (The first `.then()` may not return the same value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise itself can be a stand-in for data that is received asynchronously...

```
api.getAsyncResult = function() {
    if (!api.asyncResult) {
        api.asyncResult = makeAsyncCalls();
    }
    return api.asyncResult;
}
```

Any number of callers at any time may now say:

```
api.getAsyncResult().then(function(result) {
    // use result, which is whatever makeAsyncCalls's promise resolves to
});
```

The first call will initiate the async work.  Subsequent calls (with the same form) will chain `then`s to that returned promise.  Subsequent to the promise completion, it will continue to deliver it's resolved value as the parameter to the function passed to `then()`

The `makeAsyncCalls()` function can maintain the state of a `api.loading` flag if you need it.  There's no need for the `api.loaded` flag if it's only purpose is to protect against redundant calls (the falsey check in the get function does that).

Comment: It took me a few times, but I think I understand. Correct me if I'm wrong (I was thinking of `then` in a sequence). Once the initial `Promise` has resolved, it maintains that state, so any call to `then` would automatically invoke the success handler, with the `asyncResult`? I just need to keep and return a local copy of it.

Comment: You have it exactly.  It will invoke the success handler with whatever the makeAsyncCalls promise resolves to.

Comment: Nah, its the less commonly understood thing about promises.  They don't just control flow for async, they can be used as *nouns*, placeholders for yet to be available data.